Does navigator.storage.persist() only protect against data removal in the case of storage pressure?
According to the MDN docs browser-stored data can be evicted in three cases:

Storage pressure eviction
Browser maximum storage exceeded eviction
Proactive eviction

For the first case - "Storage pressure eviction" - the docs mention that it's possible to avoid data loss by using navigator.storage.persist()
Is this the only case where navigator.storage.persist() has an effect, or does it also have an effect in the other cases?
I'm particularly concerned about "Proactive eviction" for Safari on iOS, since data can be removed after 7 days of inactivity

Yes, it has an effect on all the cases. According to the specification

persistent buckets cannot be cleared without consent by the user

So the user agent (the browser) should not attempt to delete the data, be it from storage pressure or from inactivity without the users approval
You can see it also on the MDN example where it reads
if (persistent) {
  console.log("Storage will not be cleared except by explicit user action");
}

Be aware that the user can still delete the data at any moment, so if the data is really sensitive you should keep a backup of it somewhere. As read here

Cookies set by server are exempt from this eviction

so you could store an id inside of a cookie and then use this id to keep a back up of the data in the server, in case your app might break if some data on the client gets lost. The client data is never reliable, so keep it in mind. But if the user grant the permission to use persist, then it should be safe from automatic deletion.

Thank you for taking the time to look into this. I'm still not sure though, because when i look at the MDN example that you referenced it says this in the else clause: console.log("Storage may be cleared by the UA under storage pressure."); So that just refers to the first of the three cases when data can be evicted, and not (for example) "Proactive eviction"

Yes, well the example was like a plus, but the main reference you must focus on is the specification. If you read this section it says "When granted to an origin, the persistence permission can be used to protect storage from the user agent’s clearing policies. The user agent cannot clear storage marked as persistent without involvement from the origin or user." so its clear that the UA cannot clear the data. It is true that the UA can define policies like proactive and storage pressure, but the permission offers protection to all UA policies.
